# Pointing Domain to Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, godaddy

Let me preface this by saying I'm a programmer not a admin. Please talk to me like I'm a 5 year old when speaking about server administration.

I have purchased both a domain and a dedicated server from GoDaddy. I have successfully installed my application on the server and tested to make sure all is functioning as it should. My problem is that I cannot get the domain I purchased to point to the server. I can access the web application by using the server IP address, but not the domain. How do I set it up so my domain points to my server?

Some details:

```
Server OS - 2008
IIS version - 7
Plesk - No
```

I contacted support, but they wanted to charge me to do it and then I still wouldn't know how. Is it too much to ask for a host of both the domain and server to set this up for me?

Comment: are you able to help us out and let us know the domain and the IP of the server? Will help us help you.

Comment: How long ago was it set up? DNS can take time to migrate to other servers.

Comment: @ccame - why don't you tell me what you would do if you had the information and I'll do it myself. I'm trying to learn. @Bart - It's been more than the suggested 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make your example.com domain point to your webserver's IP address by **[setting a DNS A Record](http://help.godaddy.com/article/666#arecs)**.

You must remember to do this with any subdomains you want to use as well.

They also seem to have a 'Total DNS Control' wizard, which will probably make it easier for you to do.  It seems that it will also guide you through setting your WHOIS info, which you will want to do as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need DNS hosting if it's not included with the packages you bought already.

You own the domain name, but that name needs to point to a DNS server, the DNS server then points to your web server and life is good.

I know GoDaddy sells packages with all of the above, and also everything a la carte.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too much to ask (although I've heard enough complaints about godaddy to not reccommend them anymore).  The way it should work is that your registrar (godaddy) should have asked what DNS host you want to point to and the DNS host should point the server by name.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know all the details I'm going to assume you only want to run a website on your domain on your server e.g no email.

If this is the case then you need to create an A record on your domain to point to your server.

To Create or Edit an A Record
Log in to your Account Manager.
In the My Products section, click Domain Manager.
Click the domain name you want to update.
In the Total DNS section, click Total DNS Control.
Click Add New A Record to add a new record, or click  for an existing record you want to edit.
Complete the following and then click OK:
Host Name — The host name the A record links to. Enter @ to map the record directly to your domain name. e.g the top level domain e.g domain.com not www.domain.com
Points to IP Address — The IP address used by your domain name for this host record. e.g the IP for your server.
TTL — How long the server should cache the information.

Wait for this to propagate upto 24 hours and everything should work provided your website is listening correctly for inbound connections to your website.

This is why I was hoping to have the domain and IP, I could have tested that your server was setup correctly rather than making the assumption that it was. I have therefore assumed that only the DNS is what needs configuring and that the site is responding as it should be.

To test this yourself you could setup a [hostfiles entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) if you don't want the wait for the DNS record to propagate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Top level domains (TLDs) are actually .com, .net, org, etc., domain.com is a domain, and www.domain.com, mail.domain.com, etc, are subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

In the Go-Daddy Control Pangel - Go to Manange your domain(s).  Go to "Total DNS Control"

Setup an A record to point to your servers new external IP address.  (One not starting with 192,10,or 172)

The A Records show up and are usable from my home machine within 5 minutes, at least for me here in SoCal.

I don't remember purchasing "total dns control" - seems like they throw it in for free - which they should.

DNS Records are like entries in your cell phone.  You don't care what someone's number is under the surface, you just need the reach them. The A record is that number.